# How to use External authentication in django app

Tags: django

I creating an app in which the authentication is done via web services of another app.
But as I m trying to understand how things will work, I m trying to figure out how I can store each user data and posts to them if I m not using Django auth and then linking the models via forgien keys.

Comment: I imagine your web service should send you authentication information that you could integrate in your app. I wonder if Django Rest Framework (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) could help

Answer (score -1):

All standard login's with other apps are done using a standard called OAuth2; Oauth2 standard allows you to login to apps with other services (Facebook, Apple, Google) while just storing a random token (not sensitive data).

[Here is a Django library](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) that makes using authenticating/logging into your app with another app's credentials super easy and secure using Oauth2.

Good luck, LMK if you need anything else!